# Error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so

Tags: opencv, cmake, cuda, shared-libraries, static-linking

Hello unfortunately I have another problem with my project. The project is a client server program and is used on two machines, one sending image data over TCP to the other. Both machines are Ubuntu 16.04 machines and have OpenCV installed, but only one possesses a CUDA graphics card and has therefore CUDA (8.0) installed, and OpenCV is configured as "WITH_CUDA ON" on the CUDA-computer.
I need to distribute the Server file as executable, because it contains source code I am not allowed to distribute. My goal now is to build an executable which can be distributed to computers (which have opencv and boost installed) independent of CUDA being installed or not.
My minimal `CmakeLists.txt` looks as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.10.0 FATAL_ERROR )
project( Testproject )

# Set c++ standard 11 flag -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if( UNIX )
    SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++11" )
endif()

# Find and include opencv ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set ( OpenCV_DIR /opt/opencv/opencv-3.0/share/OpenCV )
set( OpenCV_FIND_QUIETLY FALSE )
find_package( OpenCV 3.0 REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

# Find Boost package -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
find_package( Boost COMPONENTS log log_setup thread system program_options REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

# Find Thread package ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
find_package( Threads )

add_executable( Server src/Server.cpp )

target_include_directories(Server PUBLIC /usr/include/spinnaker
                                       PRIVATE ./src/ 
                                       PRIVATE ../build/ )

target_link_libraries( Server ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} Spinnaker )
```

On the host machine with CUDA installed, the program builds and runs perfectly. On the non-CUDA machine I get the error:

```
./Server: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot openshared object file: No such file or directory.
```

The strange thing is, CUDA itself is not being used by my code, it seems to be OpenCV that includes the CUDA library but doesn't distribute it. Can anybody help me with the CMakeLists.txt to make Cmake to distribute the libcudart.so.8.0 or better to link it statically within the executable?
How can I check which libs are really linked statically? `ldd Server` delivers a list with all dependencies, OpenCV does not occur, but boost. This means that boost is linked dynamically and OpenCV statically, right? Then how could boost being linked statically, too?

Thank you very much for your help again.

Edit 1: In the meanwhile I tried to follow your comments, and it was possible to copy the `libcudart.so.8.0` to the non-CUDA computer, and run the program this way. But I would really like to know how to create a Cmake project which statically links the CUDA library, such that it not has to be copied manually. Unfortunately the linked CUDA documentation doesn't help me, I couldn't manage it.

Comment: "OpenCV that includes the CUDA library but doesn't distribute it". What do you mean by distribute in this context? If a library has a dynamic dependency it is *your* responsibility to make sure all the dependencies are available, not the library or the build system

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, so would you suggest to simply copy the libcudart.so.8.0 to other computers even if they don't have CUDA cards installed?
The strange thing about OpenCV is, that even if you don't use CUDA code OpenCV links against CUDA, but if I link OpenCV statically it only links the OpenCV libraries, not libcudart.so. So how can I have this library being statically linked, too?

Comment: yes, you should probably distribute the libcudart.so library also.  If a library is dynamically linked to your application, then your application has a dependency on that library, where ever you run it.  That library must be provided, because it is linked, whether you use it or not.  Alternatively, you could statically link to cudart, which would bundle it with your application.  But if the dependency is arising through the use of OpenCV that is dynamicallly linked, then you would have to track that down.  On linux, `ldd` will tell you what had better be present for your app to run.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, probably I expressed myself unclear. I exactly want to link statically to OpenCV and CUDA. OpenCV is built with BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF, and is not listed when typing ldd. But how to achieve that with CUDA?

Comment: Did you build the library on the CUDA machine and then copy the binary over to the non-CUDA machine? Because that probably won't work. If you link OpenCV statically, you will need to separate binaries, one for CUDA machines and one for non-CUDA machines.

Comment: recent versions of CUDA link to cudart statically by default.  The method to statically link to cudart is covered in the [nvcc guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html).

Comment: @ComicSansMS until now I even did not try to copy it to ne non-CUDA machine, but I will try in a few minutes. Please try to explain the separation a bit more detailed, how can I achieve that in a Cmake project?

Comment: @RobertCrovella I read the nvcc guide and found that --cudart ist set to static by default, but why is the library then required on the non-CUDA machine if it is linked statically within the binary? And yes I tried to find out how to manage the static linking with the guide, but I didn't get it with Cmake. So am I doing s.th. completely wrong or is there only a command missing?
And why, if CUDA links statically by default isn't it linking to the libcudart_static.a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally I figured it out and solved the problem. In the end, your comments lead me to the solution. I simply forgot to specify the CUDA library explicitly, which I didn't know I have to do.
I changed

```
target_link_libraries( Server ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} Spinnaker )
```

to

```
target_link_libraries( Server ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} Spinnaker ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} )
```

It is now, as noted in the comments, by default linked statically.